# RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

Tags: networking, linux-kernel

In fact, I want to use pipework to add an ipoib interface into docker container.
Pipework use ip command to do this. But when running the command...

```
ip link add link ib0 name ib0.2613 type ipoib
```

I get

> RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

I searched google and find [this](https://superuser.com/questions/232807/iproute2-not-functioning-rtnetlink-answers-operation-not-supported)

It list all the kernel configuration that iproute2 need. I try this ,but it dosn't work for me.
**My OS is "3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu".**

Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: This could be due to some mistake in the command you are writing. recheck it

Comment: @Mazhar The command is ok. All the answer are related to the kernel configration.

Answer (score 36):

I got a similar error,
you should try this:

```
# apt-get install wireguard-dkms wireguard-tools linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

It worked for me, kernel headers missing :shrug:

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 but also needed to install sudo apt install openresolv. Reference: https://github.com/StreisandEffect/streisand/issues/1434

Comment: On Raspberry Pi I ran `pivpn -wg` to update Wireguard which fixed the problem for me.

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 94 not upgraded.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're missing linux-headers. That was my case when I tried to install wireguard and got similar error after typing `sudo ip link add dev wg0 type wireguard`.

I resolved this by installing the linux-headers corresponding to my kernel version.
In my case, I had kernel version 4.9.0-8-amd and so I installed the package `linux-headers-4.9.0-8-amd`:

`sudo apt install linux-headers-4.9.0-8-amd`

There is little informations about this on the internet and I had to find this on the [wiki of ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WireGuard).

Comment: This problem can also occur later. Say WireGuard was installed correctly. After a few weeks there will be a kernel update, which will be installed. From this point on, the old headers no longer fit the new kernel. I have discussed the issue in [my blog post](https://www.tsommer.org/blog/setting-up-wireguard).

Answer (score 1):

Update the kernel version to 4.17 or above

Comment: I was 4.19 on Debian Buster and I had this problem. It was resolved by upgrading to kernel version 5.10 from buster backports.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to disable the secure boot in the bios / uefi and then to reboot my laptop. After that, no more "RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported" issue !